# hudson.remoting.ProxyException: net.sf.json.JSONException: Invalid JSON String

Tags: json, jenkins-pipeline

Facing below error while trying to parse the json file in Jenkins

```
def appconfig="./appSettings.json"
def testconfig= readJSON file: appconfig;
```

Json File

```
{
  "Configuration": {
    "ConnectionString": "",
    "ConnectionString2": "",
    "UnProcessedHeaderFilePath": "\\\\edisilon01\\prod\\Reporting\\GET\\Header-{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.txt",
    "UnProcessedDetailFilePath": "\\\\edisilon01\\prod\\Reporting\\GET\\Detail-{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.txt",
    "ApplicationTriggerFile": "\\\\edisilon01\\PROD\\Reporting\\InputFiles\\Factor\\DR\\Factor.txt",
    "DB2ConnectionString": ""
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "\\\\ECPCICS\\Files\\Generator\\log\\log-.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Error**

> hudson.remoting.ProxyException: net.sf.json.JSONException:
>   Invalid JSON String   at
>   net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:143)    at
>   net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:103)    at
>   net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:84)     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.json.ReadJSONStepExecution.doRun(ReadJSONStepExecution.java:77)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.AbstractFileOrTextStepExecution.run(AbstractFileOrTextStepExecution.java:32)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: According to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ it's valid JSON. Maybe a peculiarity of the specific parser. Try to remove stuff from the JSON until parsing succeeds to narrow down the problematic part.

Answer (score 3):

"readJSON [...] may fail due to leading and trailing whitespace." https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-55559?focusedCommentId=377706&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-377706

The proposed fix is to use

```
readJSON(text: readFile("./appSettings.json").trim())
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers regarding leading/trailing whitespace, this can also be caused by a byte order mark at the start of the file.

I changed the encoding of my file from UTF-8 with BOM to UTF-8 and it fixed the problem.